# on route change, `directive` not getting `$route` class name

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my app, initializing I am adding each page a class as like this:

```
$routeProvider
            .when ("/", {
                templateUrl : "views/login/login.html",
                controller  : "loginController",
                className   : "body-login" //class name for login page
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/home", {
                templateUrl : "views/home/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController",
                className   : "body-home"  //class name for home page
        });
```

It works fine. the problem is, i have `directive` with conditional template loading. when the page is changed by user on click of a link, the `directive` is not working by the condition.

In case if i manually refresh (after page load) the `directive` works fine. how to sole this issue?

here is my directive:

```
var galleryMenu = ['$route','$timeout', function ($route, $timeout) {

    var page = $route.current.className || 'body-home'; //navigating page not updating the class name. but refresh do the correct job

        return {

            replace : true,

            template : function () {

            return galleryMenuItem(page); //passing page here.

        },

        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.galleryProject = function () {

                scope.galleryShow = !scope.galleryShow;
                scope.appsList = !scope.appsList;

                if(scope.galleryShow) {

                    $timeout(function () {
                        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
                    }, 10)

                }

            }


        }

    }

}];

angular
    .module("tcpApp")
    .directive('galleryMenu', galleryMenu);
```

Do i require to change the way how I do the picking up the `class` name or do i need to refresh on page load? - i tried with on page load approach but not working.

here is the code i tried with :

```
    angular.module("tcpApp", ["ngRoute","ngResource", "ngAnimate"])

        .run(['$route', function ($route) {

            $route.reload(); //but not working!

        }])

My Template Function :

var galleryMenuItem = function (page) {

    var html = "";

    switch(page) {

        case 'body-home' :
            html += '<div class="galleryMenu"><a class="projects" ng-click="galleryProject(projects)">projects</a></div>';
            break;

        case 'body-projectSummary' :

            html += '<div class="galleryMenu"><a class="live" ng-click="galleryMenu(live)" href="#">live</a>'
            html += '<a class="visual" ng-click="galleryMenu(visual)" href="#">visuals</a>'
            html += '<a class="projects" ng-click="galleryProject(projects)">shows</a></div>';
            break;

    }

    return html;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this on $routeChangeSuccess. However you will need a slight design change in the way you set template. The template should be a html and you could bind the class name as an expression/scope variable within the template. Then on $routeChangeSuccess with the directive get the class name from the current route and update the scope. Then the template gets updated.

```
//psuedo code
scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
  function(event, next, current) {
    $scope.classname = current.classname;
});
```

Comment: According to you , i need to place the `$routeChangeSuccess` to `link` method. but how to pass the `$scope.classname` to template then?

Comment: Actually I am keeping the class name at the `$routeProvider`, from there i am updating in to `body` element.

Comment: What I meant is, in your template you should bind the scope variable. If you are building your template based on some condition of the classname, then then you can use the same condition within the html using the scope variable. That is, instead of passing the variable to template function, the variable is now available for the template html to manipulated within.

Comment: I have updated my template function in the question. can you please show me away to add the `expression` here please?

Comment: `$scope.classname` throws error as '$scope` is undefined.

Comment: can you give further details please?

Comment: You need to use scope within link function. $scope, i just specified as sample code.

Comment: I understand that, you want me to use the `expression` here. But I am not getting that. can you show me a `if else` or `ng-if` with multiple template supply?

Comment: In your directive, template should point to say. /gallery.html. And in your html, <div ng-if="classname==='body-home'"><div class="galleryMenu"><a class="projects" ng-click="galleryProject(projects)">projects</a></div><div ng-if="classname==='body-projectSummary'"class="galleryMenu"><a class="live" ng-click="galleryMenu(live)" href="#">live</a> where classname is set in scope within directive.

Comment: Makes sense. let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81962/discussion-between-user2024080-and-bharat).